# PHP not running on MacOS Monterey 12.4

Tags: php, macos, apache, configuration

I recently switched from Linux/Ubuntu to Mac. I Installed Apache2 and PHP 8 using homebrew on my MacOS Monterey 12.4 which came preinstalled with my MacBook Pro (M1). I have successfully configured the Apache and it is working perfectly as I am able to access my localhost. I have even changed the document root from its default location to my customized location (in my home directory)
After Successfully installing apache I installed php. I verified this by running the following commands

```
isthakur@Inders-MacBook-Pro apache2 % php -v
PHP 8.1.6 (cli) (built: May 12 2022 23:30:39) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.6, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.1.6, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

PHP is installed on following location `/opt/homebrew/bin/php`
but I am unable to get output on browser I have created a php file on my document root with following codes and named it test.php

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

When I try to open this file through browser (http://localhost/test.php) the codes are displayed on browser which means that server is not processing PHP.
Any kind of help is welcome and I thank everyone in anticipation.
Regards

Comment: You should just open http://localhost to check if Apache2 is running at all. Also look at the apache2 config to see where the paths are located.

Comment: Thanks for the response.
Localhost is working properly and I am able to see html pages through webserver. The only problem is that php was not registered with apache.

Comment: after reading blogs and responses online I found that MacOS comes preinstalled with apache and even php was pre installed prior to MacOS Monterey (12) So I reset my Mac and found that apache is preinstalled and I just need to run it using following command

Answer (score 0):

after reading blogs and responses online I found that MacOS comes preinstalled with apache and even php was pre installed prior to MacOS Monterey (12) So I reset my Mac and found that apache is preinstalled and I just need to run it using following command
`sudo apachectl start`
and I can access apache. Since PHP was not installed I need to install it using homebrew. after installing the php I saw that I need to modify my https.conf file as following.

```
To enable PHP in Apache add the following to httpd.conf and restart Apache:
    LoadModule php_module /opt/homebrew/opt/php/lib/httpd/modules/libphp.so

    <FilesMatch \.php$>
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
    </FilesMatch>

Finally, check DirectoryIndex includes index.php
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

The php.ini and php-fpm.ini file can be found in:
    /opt/homebrew/etc/php/8.1/

To restart php after an upgrade:
  brew services restart php
Or, if you don't want/need a background service you can just run:
  /opt/homebrew/opt/php/sbin/php-fpm --nodaemonize
```

Comment: Even this did not work properly so I had to install apache using homebrew and then configure the httpd.conf that belongs to homebrew installation.